# Web Service call results in an System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00

Tags: web-services, iis, soap, exception, .net-2.0

I get the following unhandled exception thrown from my web service - this isn't anything to do with my code and it only happens intermittently when calling the server asynchronously many times. I've included the code response object I get returned as well as this is the only thing that comes back (in this cause the generic response is a List of String).
Has anyone come across this before of know why a web service might throw this?

Entire Stack Trace:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 4, position -88.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Int32 pos, Char invChar)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseNumericCharRefInline(Int32 startPos, Boolean expand, BufferBuilder internalSubsetBuilder, Int32& charCount, EntityType& entityType)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPartsLibraryService.Read29_GenericResponseOfListOfString(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPartsLibraryService.Read34_UploadPartsResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer5.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
```

Simple Response object (pseudocode):

```
Public Class GenericResponse(Of T)
    Public Enum StateOptions

    Private _result As T
    Private _state As StateOptions
    Private _msg As String

    Public Property Result() As T
    Public Property State() As StateOptions
    Public Property Message() As String
End Class
```

I ran fiddler, but this was the only out of ordinary result I haven't seen, but I don't think it would cause the problem I'm experiencing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><UploadPartsResponse xmlns="http://autovhc.co.uk/"><UploadPartsResult><Result><string>--------------------------------------------------
01/06/2011 14:38:33
Upsert Exception
Backend sent unrecognized response type: &#x0;
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.&lt;ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3&gt;d__a.MoveNext() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlState.cs:line 966
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1163
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1181
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1367
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 523
   at VHC.Connections.DataAccess2.DataAccess.sqlNonQuery(NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd, Boolean closeConnection) in E:\svn_repository\vhc.server.solution\vhc.connections\Tags\v_3_0_0_5\New\ConnectionProxys\DataAccess.vb:line 119
   at VHC.Connections.DataAccess2.DataAccess.sqlNonQuery(NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd) in E:\svn_repository\vhc.server.solution\vhc.connections\Tags\v_3_0_0_5\New\ConnectionProxys\DataAccess.vb:line 97
   at PartsLibServerSideClasses.DAO.PLM_PsaFormat_DAO.Update(PartLibraryPartTO part, Int32 entityref, NpgsqlConnection conn) in C:\Applications\PartsImporter\Import_Library-Stable\PartsLibServerSideClasses\DAO\PSA\PLM_PsaFormat_DAO.vb:line 61
   at PartsLibServerSideClasses.DAO.PLM_PsaFormat_DAO.Upsert(PartLibraryPartTO part, Int32 entityref) in C:\Applications\PartsImporter\Import_Library-Stable\PartsLibServerSideClasses\DAO\PSA\PLM_PsaFormat_DAO.vb:line 21
   at PartsLibServerSideClasses.Parsing.PartsLibraryManager.SubmitPartToLibrary(PartLibraryPartWorkSegmentContainer partContainer) in C:\Applications\PartsImporter\Import_Library-Stable\PartsLibServerSideClasses\BOL\PartsLibraryManager.vb:line 70
</string></Result><State>Fail</State></UploadPartsResult></UploadPartsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you have the response in text form?

Comment: I couldn't see anything that might caused this... has anyone come across the issue before?

Comment: If it's not your code, then maybe it's because of something your code is calling?

Comment: @John This is a possibility, I wonder if it is something to do with NpgSql or .Net Framework, but I'm not sure how to properly test that.

Comment: Hint: it's not the .NET Framework.

Comment: I will try to serialise the response object -I might be able to detect the problem by converting the serialised string to hex - do you think this (http://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/vbnet-hex-to-string-conversion/) is the best method, or will I be able to use String.Format (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) - though it doesn't look like it will work on a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before in bug code that did not encode or remove 0 when users were copying/pasting values into a database field from another application and the zero was then coming out for those records all the way to the xml parser.

Comment: The source data is from a files. To get these files into the database we parse each line of the file into an object and a collection of these objects gets sent to the web service where it is then upserted into the db. So there isn't any copy/pasting and the data being returned has already been though the serialisation process.

Comment: I was not suggesting that your NULL has been inserted the same way, only that you should check the data in the database carefully to see if that is where it is stored in the first place or the files that the data comes from.  This can happen also when a unicode character is inserted literally into non-unicode data without proper encoding. (one of the two bytes of unicode is often 0)

Comment: I checked, but couldn't see anything that was causing this. +1 for the idea though.